# Sending multiple emails in magento

Tags: php, email, magento

I'm working on a magento project which involves some sensitive information, so please keep that in mind before asking for more information.

Basically, I'm trying to send two emails with different templates to two different addresses. I followed the tutorial on the inchoo website (the one about using templates, since the templates are custom templates).

To shed a little more light on the subject, I'm loading two customers (think of them as buyer and seller), when the buyer does what he's supposed to do, IE, buy, the seller gets an email saying that the buyer wants so and so from him. At the same time, the buyer also gets an email, saying that he initiated the buying procedure and he should wait for a reply from the seller.
So, in the example above, the seller gets the email, then the buyer gets his email, but also receives the one intended to the seller. I would need a nudge in the right direction to keep the emails distinct.

Thanks for bearing with me and thanks in advance for any replies I may get.

Edited to add full code

$worker = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($owner);

```
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer')->load($customer);

    $customerAddress = Mage::getSingleton('customer/address')->load($customer->getDefaultBilling())->format('html');

    $emailTemplate = Mage::getSingleton('core/email_template')->loadDefault('airhotels_worker_email_notification_template');

    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    $emailTemplateVariables['worker'] = $worker->getFirstname() . ' ' . $worker->getLastname();
    $emailTemplateVariables['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
    $emailTemplateVariables['start'] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($start));
    $emailTemplateVariables['end'] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($end));
    $emailTemplateVariables['account'] = Mage::getUrl('custom/mycontroller/jobs');

    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($senderName);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderEmail);
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('A new order for your services');

    $emailTemplate->send($worker->getEmail(), $worker->getFirstname() . ' ' . $worker->getLastname(), $emailTemplateVariables);

    unset($emailTemplate);
    unset($emailTemplateVariables);
    unset($processedTemplate);

    $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('airhotels_customer_email_notification_template');

    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    $emailTemplateVariables['customer'] = $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname();
    $emailTemplateVariables['worker'] = $worker->getFirstname() . ' ' . $worker->getLastname();
    $emailTemplateVariables['date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start));
    $emailTemplateVariables['start'] = date('H:i:s', $start);
    $emailTemplateVariables['end'] = date('H:i:s', $end);
    $emailTemplateVariables['worker_address'] = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($worker->getDefaultBilling())->format('html');

    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($senderName);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($senderEmail);
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('You have placed a new order');

    $emailTemplate->send($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getLastname(), $emailTemplateVariables);
```

The unsets are just a thing I was trying out atm.

Comment: I think it will be very difficult for people to help you figure out why it's emailing the seller letter to both parties without seeing the code that sends the emails. You can edit out any sensitive information.

Comment: I'll post some code right away, I don't think the email sending is as important as my client claims it to be.